# Symfony2 and web service

Tags: json, web-services, symfony, curl

I'm trying to get data by web service with symfony2. To explain, i have a form with two fields (email and password). i need to send this parameters in a `JSON` array to an `URL`, and this one should send me a response. I searched a bundle to do this and i found `LswApiCaller`, but this bundle doesn't work with `JSON` array. So i tried to use directly curl function like this :

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$payload = json_encode($parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Content-Length: '.strlen($payload),
    )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But it's doesn't work too, `$result`  is empty i got no response. Someone know what is the best practice to get my response with my `URL` and my parameters ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the server returns response and does not fail? You could try to look at curl last session error (if there is any, of course) by curl_error() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: I'd also suggest you to make request by rest app from the browser or by custom form to the server to be sure the server works fine. If everything is ok on the server you can move on and debug your curl.

Comment: I tried the request with SoapUI and the resquest works fine. i got a white page when i tried by code. maybe i need to save my response in xml file no ? because print_r() maybe doesn't work with web service response ? I will try curl_error. thanks

Comment: I think if it's soap server you have to use some kind of php soap client - not curl.

Comment: No i use soap ui to test the url with the params, i don't use soap server. i think i need to use curl.

Comment: that not my choice :/ nobody know if there is a bundle to do HTTP request ? i found buzz or guzzle.

Comment: There is no need to use a special bundle for that purposes.

Comment: What was the result of debugging? What does return curl_error()? Provide working sample of request with soap ui.

Comment: The error returned is : Curl error: Could not resolve host : myhostiused.fr

Comment: EDIT : I haven't any errors :  Operation completed without any errors

Comment: It's difficult to say where is the problem without details. If you have any other details (code of soap ui request, for example) please provide them.